# I roll a dice multiple times. After how many rolls should I expect to find $n$ consecutive rolls with the same number?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a dice with $d$ faces. I keep rolling it and recording the number that I see after each roll. What is the expected value of the number of rolls I have to make before seeing a sequence of the same number repeated at least $n$ times?

For example, if $d = 6$ and $n = 3$, after how many rolls should I expect to see one of these: (1, 1, 1) or (2, 2, 2) or (3, 3, 3) or (4, 4, 4) or (5, 5, 5) or (6, 6, 6)?

---

Here's what I tried:

There are $d$ such sequences out of $d^n$ possible sequences. The probability of an $n$-long sequence of being one of them is therefore $p = d^{1 - n}$. The expected value of trials before reaching one of those sequences therefore should be the inverse of that probability: $E = d^{n - 1}$.

However I know that's not correct: both because I ran a numeric simulation and I can see that the formula does not work, and because that kind of reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  I suggest doing it recursively in $n$.

Comment: I added my effort but honestly I don't have many clues about how to approach this problem. I have experience with predicting a _single_ outcome, but here we're talking about a _sequence_ of outcomes, and I don't know how to do that. I don't understand what "doing it recursively in $n$" means

Comment: If you are familiar with conditional expectation, you can condition on whether the sequence is a perfect one (i.e., it is exactly $n$ rolls of the same number) or whether it isn’t. In the second case, we can further condition on *where* the first occurrence of a roll which is different than the first roll is. This will give you an equation in which you can solve for $\operatorname{E}(X)$. The formula is quite nice!